# Handling multiple windows in PYQT

Tags: python, pyqt

My PYQT4 GUI was getting very lengthy, so I split up the pages to a .py file for each page.

I am trying to traverse the pages, using buttons, but now I cant get it to work :)

Here is what I have so far:

**mainwindow.py**

```
import windowConvertor


        self.button2 = QtGui.QPushButton('Convertor Page', self)
        self.button2.clicked.connect(self.pageTwo)

    def pageTwo(self):

        self.hide()
        pagetwo = windowConvertor.convertorPage
        pagetwo.show(self)
```

**windowconvertor.py**

```
class convertorPage(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        print "YOU MADE IT!!"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you don't understand classes, objects, instantiation and what `self` is.

These lines are completely wrong:

```
pagetwo = windowConvertor.convertorPage
pagetwo.show(self)
```

This code gets a reference to the `convertorPage` class, and stores a reference to it in `pagetwo`. You then call `pagetwo.show` which calls the function `show` in the `convertorPage` class and passes it a reference to the object for the first page (`self` since the `pageTwo` method, presumably resides within the class for the first page).

Instead, you should instantiate the `convertorPage` class with:

```
pagetwo = windowConvertor.convertorPage()
```

This creates an object of type `convertorPage` and stores it in `pagetwo`. 
You can then call show on this object:

```
pagetwo.show()
```

Note: When calling a method of an object, a reference to the object is implicitly passed as the first argument. There is no need to specify it explicitly.

Final notes:

- Please read up on object oriented programming (and object oriented GUIs). Your code shows you don't quite grasp this yet and you will need to wrap your head around it to effectively program with PyQt.
- There is a further issue with your code. You are not storing a reference to your new window (`pagetwo`) which will be garbage collected when the `pageTwo` method finishes running. You need to fix this by either storing it as an instance attribute (`self.pagetwo = ...`) or having an overarching parent widget which you pass in when instantiating `convertorPage`.